# htaccess redirect duplicate content from hosting company

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, duplicates

Please help me to avoid duplicate content of my site

I have a web site, let say www.example.com.

My hosting company (netfirms) also provide address for our web site using their domain, which is example.netfirms.com

How to redirect all links to example.netfirms.com to www.example.com ??

please provide SEO friendly solution

regards

eddy ajis

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Apul Gupta
Thanks for your help

So, my htaccess will look like this ?


    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^netfirms\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
i add www because i have a htaccess rule that force www. version of domain to be used.

Comment: First check my solution without any modification & let me know if that works. If so, accept my answer & then we can move to modifications